How to convert html view to pdf using jspdf npm library?
When i am using jspdf library to convert the html view to pdf its giving me below error.

TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver #<WrappedPromise> at Promise.then (<anonymous>) at Promise.wrappedThen (/Desktop/projectName/winston-helper/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:524:27) at Promise.<anonymous> (/Desktop/projectName/module2/node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.node.min.js:197:10075)

Below is the code snippet. the node version is 12.18.0 jspdf version installed is 2.5.1
const { jsPDF } = require('jspdf');
const pdf = new jsPDF(options);
pdf.html(htmlTemplate, {
callback: function (pdf) {
const buffer = pdf.output();
return buffer;
},
});


Why you are using node version 12.18.0?

This is the current node that is used in the project. Upgrading node would be a bigger task and that will require some other things to be done.
